# Error while checking forgot password request

Tags: nodemon, mailtrap

"data and salt arguments required",
"stack": "Error: data and salt arguments required\n    at Object.hash (C:\Users\shant\Desktop\jvlcart\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:137:17)\n    at C:\Users\shant\Desktop\jvlcart\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:29:12\n    at new Promise ()\n    at module.exports.promise (C:\Users\shant\Desktop\jvlcart\node_modules\bcrypt\promises.js:20:12)\n    at Object.hash (C:\Users\shant\Desktop\jvlcart\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:133:25)\n    at model. (C:\Users\shant\Desktop\jvlcart\backend\models\userModel.js:41:39)\n    at callMiddlewareFunction (C:\Users\shant\Desktop\jvlcart\node_modules\kareem\index.js:628:27)\n    at model.next (C:\Users\shant\Desktop\jvlcart\node_modules\kareem\index.js:93:7)\n    at _next (C:\Users\shant\Desktop\jvlcart\node_modules\kareem\index.js:146:10)\n    at C:\Users\shant\Desktop\jvlcart\node_modules\kareem\index.js:653:30"

Comment: Learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) then [edit] your question and properly format the stack trace.